# Matplotlib - Extending MaxNLocator (or Date Locators)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to both simultaneously specify the location of major ticks and 'auto'-fill the remaining up to a certain number like `MaxNLocator`?

Eg. I have data from 2010-present. I want to specify that I want 10 ticks. If I first specify I want years located with `matplotlib.dates.YearLocator()`, this would have found 5 ticks (2011,2012,2011,2013,2014,2015 - starting in January) and have 5 remaining ticks. Can I automatically select these then using functionality from `MaxNLocator()`?

Currently I define my own methods for `FuncFormatter` like this:

```
year = 0
major_ticks = []

def formatter(x, pos):
    x = matplotlib.dates.num2date(x)
    print x
    print pos
    global year
    global major_ticks
    if x.year > year:
        fmt = '%B \n %Y'
        label = x.strftime(fmt)
        major_ticks.append(pos)
    else:
        fmt = '%B'
        label = x.strftime(fmt)
    year = x.year
    return label

loc = MaxNLocator(nbins=8)
fmt = FuncFormatter(formatter)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df.index, df['col1'])
plt.show()
```

This is almost getting there. This displays the first time a tick has a year change with the year, otherwise it just displays the month. It's progress, but not quite right. The month with a year will be whichever month is first displayed, chosen by the `MaxNLocator`, where I want to specify that all January's are displayed and have their year displayed, as well.

[image]

This is my output of the code above - I want to force January's to display and evenly distribute my ticks otherwise. Thanks for you help.
Edit: I haven't made any progress on this - any ideas?

Comment: Probably have to write a new locator class.  Can you make this an issue on gh?